# All images show up in simulator but not on real device

Tags: ios, image, ios-simulator

In my app I have a all of my colors and assets in 2 asset files -

[image]

Some images are put on `viewControllers` in storyboard from `Media Library` and some programmatically but all of them don't appear on device. I tried unchecking the box on Clears Craphics Context and restarting the simulator but that didn't work.

I tried using the image full name with `.png` but now I got the image with like this below.

[image]

[image]

Are there any other workarounds ?

**EDIT: Just to update I was talking about a build on TestFlight that didn't show me any images when I was trying the app. Now I tried erasing all content and settings and connected my mac with device and every image showed up as normal. Can this be problem only with TestFlight or I just solved the problem ?**

Comment: First run your app and check, is you still facing same issue?

Comment: remove the png and try once

Comment: I am facing this issue with .spriteatlas in the catalog. Everything was working and then after some image updates, the world broke. When you say you erased settings, what exactly did you erase?

Comment: sry I can't remember this was long time ago

Answer (score 0):

You are close. In your finder, under your projects Images.xcassets file, your images need to be in assets file called `someimage.imageset` with a contents.json file which specifies the image size (x3, x2, x1) for device sizes. This enables using images in your app in the way your example picture shows.

After implementing the images with contents.json file your image will appear.

Here is a sample contents.json file from [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_ref-Asset_Catalog_Format/ImageSetType.html):

```
{
   "images" : [
      {
         "idiom" : "universal",
         "scale" : "1x"
      },
      {
         "graphics-feature-set" : "metal1v2",
         "idiom" : "universal",
         "filename" : "Llama.png"
         "scale" : "2x"
      },
      {
        "graphics-feature-set" : "metal2v2",
        "idiom" : "universal",
        "memory" : "2GB",
        "scale" : "3x"
     }
  ],
  "info" : {
     "author" : "com.developerName",
     "version" : 1
  },
  "properties" : {
     "on-demand-resources : [
        "llama",
        "mountain"
     ]
  }
}
```